# Different methods to secure eject removable usb drive?

Tags: usb-drive, eject

To secure unmount a usbdrive i use the eject button next to the drive-icon in nautilus before i plug it from the usb jack.
But not always nautilus is in use and sometimes i have to start extra it for this purpose.

Which other different methods exist to quick secure unmount (eject) a removable usbdrive?

Comment: You can also [drag and drop it to the Trash](http://askubuntu.com/questions/465019/trash-media-to-eject-it-like-in-os-x).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Desktop Icon

You can right click on the icon on the desktop and click 'Safely Remove Drive':

[image]

## Docky Docklet

If you use [docky](http://packages.ubuntu.com/docky), you can use the 'Mounter' docklet.

[image]

and right click on the icon and click 'Eject'.

[image]

## Command

From a terminal, you can use:

```
umount /media/7890-FB2E
```

replacing `/media/7890-FB2E` with the path its mounted to.

You can also do this from the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- You can also install **[indicator-usb](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7138409/indicator-usb/indicator-usb-0.2.1.deb)**
- After installation add **indicator-usb** to your Startup Applications.
  [image]
  [image]
- **[Source](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7138409/indicator-usb/indicator.html)**

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this [indicator applet](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/safely-remove-usb-drives-using-a-nifty-application-indicator-updated-with-new-icon/).